# How can I pass parameters to a Crystal Report from my GridView?

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, webforms

I have an existing SQL database and a ASP.NET application. My application has two existing `GridViews` and login functions. I also have an existing Crystal Report designed to automatically create a receipt from my SQL database. This is done by the user filling out 3 specific parameters, and the rest of the data (which are in parallel with those parameters) will automatically fill out the crystal report.

I want to create a print button in my `GridView` to automatically fill out the 3 parameters in the Crystal Report. This is an attempt to make my application more user friendly. In short, the user would push the print button in its new column in the `GridView`, and the 3 parameters would be automatically picked up and filled into the Crystal Report.

My parameters are: "EmpID", "KeyControl", and "ControlNumber". My crystal report label is "x.rpt"

Here is my `GridView` markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridKeyAndBuildingInformation" runat="server"  CssClass="style3" 
              AllowSorting ="True" 
              AutoGenerateColumns ="False" 
              AllowPaging="True"
              DataKeyNames="KeyRefId"
              OnRowCancelingEdit="gridKeyAndBuildingInformation_RowCancelingEdit" 
              onPageIndexChanging="gridKeyAndBuildingInformation_PageIndexChanging"
              OnRowDataBound="gridKeyAndBuildingInformation_RowDataBound"
              OnRowEditing="gridKeyAndBuildingInformation_RowEditing" 
              OnRowUpdating="gridKeyAndBuildingInformation_RowUpdating" 
              OnRowCommand="gridKeyAndBuildingInformation_RowCommand" 
              ShowFooter="True"
              OnRowDeleting="gridKeyAndBuildingInformation_RowDeleting"                                    
              AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EFEFEF" 
              EditRowStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" 
              HeaderStyle-BackColor="#77b218"
              OnSorting="gridKeyAndBuildingInformation_Sorting" 
              BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
              BorderColor="#999999" 
              BorderStyle="Solid" 
              BorderWidth="3px" 
              CellPadding="4" 
              EnableModelValidation="True" 
              ForeColor="Black" 
              CellSpacing="2">
<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="EmpID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderText" sortexpression="EmpID">
    <ItemTemplate>                     
    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpID") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpID") %>' Width="50px"></asp:TextBox> 
</EditItemTemplate> 
<FooterTemplate> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewEmpID" runat="server"  Width="50px"></asp:TextBox> 
</FooterTemplate> 
<HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderText" />
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="ControlNumber" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderText" sortexpression="ControlNumber">
<ItemTemplate>                     
    <asp:Label ID="lblControlNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ControlNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtControlNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ControlNumber") %>' Width="50px"></asp:TextBox> 
</EditItemTemplate> 
<FooterTemplate> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewControlNumber" runat="server"  Width="50px"></asp:TextBox> 
</FooterTemplate> 
<HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderText" />
</asp:TemplateField> 

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="KeyNumber" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderText" sortexpression="KeyNumber">
<ItemTemplate>                     
    <asp:Label ID="lblKeyNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("KeyNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtKeyNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("KeyNumber") %>' Width="50px"></asp:TextBox> 
</EditItemTemplate> 
<FooterTemplate> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewKeyNumber" runat="server"  Width="50px"></asp:TextBox> 
</FooterTemplate> 
<HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderText" />
</asp:TemplateField> 

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="False">
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton> 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton> 
</EditItemTemplate> 
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="AddNew" Text="Add New"></asp:LinkButton> 
</FooterTemplate> 
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton> 
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField> 

<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True" /> 
<asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Print" ShowHeader="True" Text="Print" />

</Columns>

<EditRowStyle VerticalAlign="Top"></EditRowStyle>
<FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
<PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<RowStyle BackColor="White" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `RowCommand` event, which would fire when you click that delete button in your `ButtonField` column.  Add this to the end of your `GridView` declaration markup (after "`CellSpacing="2"`" but before the "`>`"):

```
OnRowCommand="gridKeyAndBuildingInformation_RowCommand"
```

And then, in your code behind you would need something like this (this is C#, if you need VB.NET let me know - this question isn't tagged with a server-side language):

```
protected void gridKeyAndBuildingInformation_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Get your ID for the row you're on
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    // Get the row the button was clicked in
    GridViewRow row = gridKeyAndBuildingInformation.Rows[ID];

    // Get the values you need from that row
    int EmpID = row.Cells[0];
    int ControlNumber = row.Cells[1];
    int KeyNumber = row.Cells[2]; 

    // Use those numbers to make your call to the Crystal Report
    // I don't know what this part would look like.
}
```

You can read more about the RowCommand event on MSDN: [GridView.RowCommand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

Comment: Its in C# and i actually found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511682/passing-parameters-to-crystal-report-from-webforms

Comment: not yet, but iam trying to figure it out from it. any help is still appreciated if anyone have experience with this.